# SQL joining tables (a,b) - but only rows from a

Tags: sql, magento, join

I want to join two tables (`sales_flat_order` & `sales_flat_order_address`). I want to use the `entity_id` from one table to match with the `parent_id` in the other table. Now there is one row for every `entity_id` but there are two rows for every parent_id. But i just want to have one row after the join.

I am using this Statement but it still returns two rows for every entity_id after the join.

```
select o.customer_email, a.prefix
from sales_flat_order o
left JOIN sales_flat_order_address a on o.entity_id = a.parent_id
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Why are there two rows, how are they different, and how do you know which row's a.prefix value you'd want to pull back?

Comment: @SpectralGhost: it's magento database schema. There are usually two address lines: billing and shipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select o.customer_email, 
     a.prefix 
from sales_flat_order o 
 left JOIN (Select  distinct a.prefix, a.parentid 
            from sales_flat_order_address) a
 on o.entity_id = a.parent_id
```

Comment: yeah thx! this one seems to be what i'm looking for. i am checking it out at the Moment. but it takes my sql client for eeeeeeeeeeeeever to compute the Statement. my pc is working since 40 minutes... is that normal?

Comment: left joins use less aount of execution time compared to inner joins and you have not specified the table size or how many rows it contains. better check for indexes for the columns used in join condition.

Comment: Pls rate the answer if it ok or helpful for you

Comment: the sales_flat_order has not so many rows (round about 200k). or do you consider that beeing alot? And what exactly do you mean by checking for Indexes for the columns?

Comment: if there is no index for u r table then the data is  heap in the sense no preplanned mechanism to retrive data in that case it take lot of time to fetch the data. that happened many times in my case. Even to get the max or min value it will take atleast 2 mins if there is considerable data and the table does not contain index.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a distinct?

```
select DISTINCT o.customer_email, a.prefix
from sales_flat_order o
left JOIN sales_flat_order_address a on o.entity_id = a.parent_id
```

Obviously this will only remove multiple rows where o.customer_email, a.prefix are in fact the same, otherwise you would need to find some way to decide which record you actually wanted... eg:

```
select o.customer_email, MIN(a.prefix)
from sales_flat_order o
left JOIN sales_flat_order_address a on o.entity_id = a.parent_id
group by o.customer_email
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  o.customer_email, oa.prefix
FROM    sales_flat_order o
LEFT JOIN
        sales_flat_order_address oa
ON      oa.entity_id =
        (
        SELECT  entity_id
        FROM    sales_flat_order_address oai
        WHERE   oai.parent_id = o.entity_id
        ORDER BY
                FIND_IN_SET(address_type, 'billing,shipping')
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

This way you will be getting the prefix from billing address (if it's set), falling back to shipping address if the billing address is not set.